# Trying to return the module import back to its original/default mock

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

In my test file, I have a **mocks** folder that has a load of exported functions. Typically, I will just use the **mocks** folder to do all of the work, but there is one case where I need to change the return value to cater for another function, I don't know how to get it back to the original/default mock.

Take the example below.

```js
// __mocks__/user.ts
export default someModuleFunction = () => {
  return 'default mock'
}

// user.test.ts
import {someModuleFunction} from 'user';
jest.mock('../users')

describe("TestFile", () => {

 it("should mock the return value in here", () => {
  (someModuleFunction as jest.Mock) = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null)
  expect(someModuleFunction).toEqual(null)
 })
 
 it("should fallback to the original default mock", async() => {
   expect(someModuleFunction).toEqual('default mock')
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to `someModuleFunction` is a mistake because ES modules are read-only, this works only because they are transpiled to CommonJS. Mocks that are supposed to be restored should never be done by reassignment. A better but still incorrect way would be to import `*` and use `spyOn` on it.

This is the case for isolated modules, a module needs to be re-imported per test:

```
 it("should mock the return value in here", () => {
  jest.isolatedModules(() => {
    jest.doMock('user', () => /* mock it */);
    const {someModuleFunction} = require('user'); // mocked
    /* require modules that depend on this mock */
  });
 })
```